# jQuery TokenInput not working (displaying search results ) with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, jquery-tokeninput

This is the javascript code I use in my page.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tokenfield").tokenInput("localhost/inkrasa3/public/hashes",
            {theme:"facebook",tokenLimit:5,preventDuplicates:true,tokenValue:"name"});
    });
</script>
```

And here is the route file.

```
Route::get('hashes',function(){
return "[{id: 1, name:\"hello\"},{id:2, name:\"sup\"}]";
});
```

What am I doing wrong? It works perfectly for hard coded array or an Json array printed by blade.
I have even tried this:

`$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#tokenfield").tokenInput("localhost/inkrasa3/public/hashes",
                {theme:"facebook",tokenLimit:5,preventDuplicates:true,tokenValue:"name",method:"post"});
        });`

with the route:

```
`Route::post('hashes',function(){
$names[] = array('id' => 0, 'name' => 'hello');
$names[] = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'sup');

return Response::json($names);
```

});`
At both times I get **404** error when I looked in browser dev tools.

Comment: When I send same url from a tab in browser all works fine. But the searchbar gets 404 error. Hope this information helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response should be of type "application/json".

Try the following code for **Laravel 4**:

```
Route::get('hashes', function()
{
    $names[] = array('id' => 0, 'name' => 'hello');
    $names[] = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'sup');

    return Response::json($names);
});
```

And for **Laravel 5** replace the return statement with:

`return response()->json($names);`

#### example with dynamic response (Laravel 4)

```
Route::get('hashes', function()
{
    // submitted letters from TokenInput
    $letters = Input::get('q');

    // search in the column "name"
    $users = User::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $letters . '%')->get();

    return Response::json($users->toArray());
});
```

the user table of course :)

```
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Peter        |
|  2 | Andy         |
|  3 | Walter       |
|  4 | ...          |
+----+--------------+
```

Comment: The suggestion box sends a request url of type: `/mainurl?q=typed_letters` . Do I need to make changes to my route for that?

Comment: The default behavior of TokenInput is GET so stay with `Route::get();` In the route function you can access the typed letters with `$letters = Input::get('q');` I have updated my answer with an example...

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. What I was doing wrong was writing entire url in the javascript and laravel appended that to the base url. So I got 404 error. All it required was the url same as route.

Comment: You're welcome! Do you use tools like Firebug or something similar to track ajax requests?

Comment: Just the inspector that comes with firefox. I figured out my mistake from there.